# Typescript - How to access base class properties

Tags: typescript, extends

I know there is some others questions with that subject, but my issue is not the same as them : I checked my class and I already use it the same way as them.
I extends a class A into a class B, and I can't access to A public properties in B. Here is my (simplified) code :

```
export class A {
    propertyA: string;

    constructor() {
        this.propertyA = "some text";
    }
}
```

---

```
import {A} from "./A";
export class B extends A {

    constructor() {
        super();
    }


    static method() {
        console.log(this.propertyA);
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to read up of the difference between static and instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot access `this` from a static method.  Remove the `static` and it should work.